# "I'm always (being) asked silly questions!" Doesn't the continuous verb form sound a bit awkward compared to the simple one?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, passive-voice, present-progressive

In order to emphasise the annoying aspect of a habit – be it someone else's or one's own – a continuous tense instead of a simple one is used:

> > *People **are** always **asking** me silly questions!*
> >
> > *I **am** always **making** the same mistakes!*

I am angry with those people or with myself, with the subject of the verb. IN THE PASSIVE, the first sentence should become:

> > *I **am** always **being asked** silly questions!*

Doesn't this sentence sound awkward? Because the agent of the passive – they who I am angry with – have disappeared from the sentence, and it is not the grammatical subject – myself – I am angry with.

Shouldn't a sentence with a simple verb form be preferred?

> > *I **am** always **asked** silly questions!*

Comment: I don't think it's awkward. It's like saying *I can't stand being kept waiting.*

Comment: For reasons which aren't 100% clear to me, *I am always being asked silly questions!* sounds fine, but *I am always making the same mistakes!* seems like something only an "Indian English" speaker would come out with. In general, standard English speakers avoid the continuous in such constructions, but ***always*** can *sometimes* make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this issue is a matter of opinion. But I think it's worth noting these figures from Google Books...

> (more formal versions)
>   1: *I am always asked that* [- **91**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20always%20asked%20that%22#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20am%20always%20asked%20that%22)
>   2:  *I am always being asked that* [- **7**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20always%20asked%20that%22#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20am%20always%20being%20asked%20that%22)
>
> (more colloquial versions)
>   3: *I'm always asked that* [- **57**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20always%20asked%20that%22)
>   4:  *I'm always being asked that* [- **15**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20always%20asked%20that%22#tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20always%20being%20asked%20that%22)

You might say the sample size is too small to draw any conclusions, but it does suggest we're almost four times more likely to use the continuous form in *relaxed, informal conversational contexts* than we are in more formal contexts.

---

I think it's specifically the word ***always*** that "licenses" the continuous form in this context. Compare...

> 5: [*I am asked this every day*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20am%20asked%20this%20every%20day%22) (normal English)
>    6: [*I am being asked this every day*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20am%20asked%20this%20every%20day%22#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20am%20being%20asked%20this%20every%20day%22) (sounds like non-standard "Indian English" to me)